# Make Traefik see containers from other networks?

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to make Traefik notice a container that belongs to a different network. Consider the following docker-compose.yml, which is the only file in that directory:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    container_name: "traefik"
    hostname: "traefik"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    command:
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{ index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}.docker.localhost`)'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--entrypoints.web.address=:80'
```

And the following project, sitting in a directory `flask`:

> flask/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  flaskapp:
      container_name: flaskapp
      build: flask_app
      expose:
       - 5000
      labels:
        traefik.enable: true
        traefik.docker.network: traefik_default
        traefik.http.routers.flaskapp.rule: Host(`flaskapp.localhost`)
        traefik.http.routers.flaskapp.entrypoints: web
```

> flask/flask_app/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN python3.8 -m pip install flask
ADD ./main.py .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ./main.py
```

> flask/flask_app/main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return "hello, world"
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I basically did `sudo docker-compose up` in both of the directories and found that `flaskapp.localhost` receives the connection, but then times out. So I tried `sudo docker network connect traefik_default flaskapp` to connect flaskapp to the traefik_default network, but this didn't seem change anything.  Why doesn't `sudo docker network connect traefik_default flaskapp` help? Is there a way to make Traefik see containers from all networks without plugging it in to theirs?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that one way to make Traefik able to access all docker-compose networks is to run it in `--net host` mode, by adding `network_mode: "host"` to its flags. Here's the modified docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    container_name: "traefik"
    hostname: "traefik"
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    command:
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{ index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}.docker.localhost`)'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--entrypoints.web.address=:80'
```

I don't unfortunately understand the security implications of this setup and thus can't tell if it's fit for production usage, but it seems to solve this particular problem.